# What is the meaning and origin of the phrase "Steal your eyes"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

I've come across this phrase only in song lyrics:

[Just then, somebody stole my eyes again](https://genius.com/Stone-sour-somebody-stole-my-eyes-lyrics) (2017)

[The loneliness of loving someone can steal your eyes](https://genius.com/Emery-hard-times-lyrics) (2015)

[You stole my eyes, so you I will take](https://genius.com/Emery-taken-for-a-bath-lyrics) (2015)

A quick google search didn't find much for this phrase, so I can only infer a meaning from context.

Comment: As you may well infer, it suggests that something or somebody is proving so attractive that you are unable to take your gaze away in spite of your desire to do so.